# How are electrical and other utilities interfaces added to an operating pressurised spacecraft?

Tags: spacecraft, habitat, vacuum, service-utilities

How are extra utility lines and pipes, like data, electrical, ?or gasses and fluids, added to a manned, pressurised and operating vehicle or habitat, in space?

A spacecraft may be launched with, perhaps, a ?small overcapacity in utilities 
ports to allow for future expansion of services, but once those ports are populated, how does one add more interface ports?

Do such techniques exist?

Has this been done, e.g. on the ISS?

What are the techniques used?

How is hull and atmospheric integrity maintained?

Can such similar techniques developed for terrestrial military submarine rescue be applied in the vacuum of space?